# Problem with simplification KroneckerDelta

Tags: bugs, simplifying-expressions, summation

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and fixed in 9.0**

---

I have:

```
Assuming[-nn <= m <= nn && m ∈ Integers, 
         Simplify[Sum[KroneckerDelta[m, n] f[n], {n, -nn, nn}]]]
```

And it gets me

$$\begin{cases}
\mathtt{2\,f[0]}&\mathtt{m}=0\\
\mathtt{f[m]}&\mathtt{True}
\end{cases}$$

Do you know why there's a factor of two if $m=0$?

Comment: Huh... returned unevaluated in Mathematica 10.3.0.

Comment: Looks like a bug; what version are you on? It's unevaluated in 10.2.

Comment: Did you try it with a fresh kernel?

Comment: In Mathematica 10.3 and 10.2 it doesn't work. I had to re-install the version 8 to get the result.

Comment: Returns unevaluated in 10.0.

Comment: I can reproduce the result in V8.

Comment: Added [tag:bugs] provisionally; we now need someone with version 9.x to test.

Answer (score 2):

There's been some progress on this input. In M11, the expression evaluates to the expected result:

```
Assuming[
    -nn<=m<=nn && m ∈ Integers,
    Sum[KroneckerDelta[m,n] f[n],{n,-nn,nn}]
]
```

> f[m]

Answer (score 1):

This bug was present in *Mathematica* version 8.0:

```
$Version
Assuming[
    -nn <= m <= nn && m \[Element] Integers, 
    Simplify[Sum[KroneckerDelta[m, n] f[n], {n, -nn, nn}]]
]
```

[image: print screen v8.0]

Since version 9.0 this `Sum` remains unevaluated:

[image: print screen v9.0]